# Sign Certificate using Server's Private Key in Android (OpenSSL)

Tags: android, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, sign

I am trying to sign the certificate inside the code using server's private key. I have stored the private key inside the res folder. The problem is I can read the key as inputstream. How should I sign the certificate with this format or how to change it to key format. Following is he code to sign the certificate.

```
X509CertificateHolder certHldr = v3Bldr
            .build( new JcaContentSignerBuilder( "SHA256" ).setProvider( "BC" ).build( keyPair.getPrivate() ) );
```

Please help me out to solve this signing issue.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really want to store server's private key in the Android application? Anyone can decompile it and extract the key

Comment: I don't see any errors or descriptions of any problems. So what is your question?